# JTable Specific Game Calculator

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener

I am trying to make a table that you input values for each column defined in the `MyTableModel` and then use the selections of Characters to make an attack per defined by the rules of the game.

I want:

- cell to beset a cell uneditable and unusable once it has used its one action per the turn
- a turn counter and a threat table kept for each monster
- to use Java swings `JTable`to display and collect data as the system runs through the attack
- to try to configure a display that shows the battle's progression through game text.

This the code that I have thus far. I was wondering why I am receiving the error of incompatible types - `found java.lang.Object but expected int` for my declaration of `HP` in `actionPerformed()` method when I believe I should have an `int`. Let me know what you think and if you have any suggestions to assist me in my endeavors. Thanks for your time.

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class EncounterCalculator extends JPanel 
                            implements ActionListener { 
    private JTable table;
    private JRadioButton Attack, Skill, Skulk;
    private JTextArea output;
    private ButtonGroup Act;
    int rowSelected;
    int ID;
    String Name;
    int maxHP;
    int HP;
    int maxMP;
    int MP;
    int attackBase;
    int attack;
    int fumbleChance;
    int criticalChance;
    int damage;
    int minDamage;
    int maxDamage;
    int defense;
    int defenseBase;
    int dodge;
    int dodgeRoll;

    public EncounterCalculator() {
        super();
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new RowListener());
        table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().
            addListSelectionListener(new ColumnListener());
        add(new JScrollPane(table));


        JRadioButton Attack = new JRadioButton("Attack");
        JRadioButton Skill = new JRadioButton("Skill");
        JRadioButton Skulk = new JRadioButton("Skulk");

        add(new JLabel("Act"));
        Act = new ButtonGroup();
        Act.add(Attack);
        Act.add(Skill);
        Act.add(Skulk);

        JPanel actPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        actPanel.add(Attack);
        actPanel.add(Skill);
        actPanel.add(Skulk);
        add(actPanel);

    }

    private JRadioButton addRadio(String text) {
        JRadioButton b = new JRadioButton(text);
        b.addActionListener(this);
        Act.add(b);
        add(b);
        return b;
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String command = event.getActionCommand();
        int rowsSelected[] = table.getSelectedRows();
        int attackersRowSelected = rowsSelected[0];
        int defendersRow = rowsSelected.length - 1;
        int defendersRowSelected = rowsSelected[defendersRow];
        if ("Attack" == command) {
        int HP = table.getValueAt(, 3);
        int damage;
        int attackBase = table.getValueAt(attackersRowSelected, 6);
        int attackRoll = generator.nextInt(100) + 1;
        int fumbleChance = table.getValueAt(attackersRowSelected, 7);
        int criticalChance = table.getValueAt(attackersRowSelected, 8);
            if (attackRoll < fumbleChance){
                damage = 0;
            } else if (attackRoll > criticalChance){
                damage = maxDamage * 2;
            } else {
                damage = generator.nextInt((maxDamage - minDamage)) + minDamage;
            }
        int attack = attackBase + attackRoll;
        int dodge = table.getValueAt(defendersRowSelected, 12);
        int dodgeRoll = generator.nextInt(100) + 1;
        if (dodge > dodgeRoll){
            damage = 0;
        }
        int defenseBase = table.getValueAt(defendersRowSelected, 11);
        int defenseRoll = generator.nextInt(100) + 1;
        int defense = defenseBase + defenseRoll;
        if (attack >= defense){
            HP = HP - damage;
            table.setValueAt(HP,defendersRowSelected, 4);


        }

        } else if ("Skill" == command) {

        } else if("Skulk" == command) {

        } 
    }

    private void outputSelection() {
    }

    private class RowListener implements ListSelectionListener {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
            if (event.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private class ColumnListener implements ListSelectionListener {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
            if (event.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private String[] columnNames = {"ID",
                                        "Name",
                                        "maxHP",
                                        "HP",
                                        "maxMP",
                                        "MP",
                                        "Att",
                                        "Fumble",
                                        "Crit", 
                                        "minDam",
                                        "maxDam",
                                        "Def",
                                        "Dodge",
                                        "Foc",
                                        "Res"};
        private Object[][] data = {
            {"1", "Character1", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"2", "Character2", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"3", "Character3", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"4", "Character4", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"5", "Character5", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"6", "Character6", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"7", "Character7", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"8", "Character8", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"9", "Character9", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"10", "Character10", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"11", "Character11", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"12", "Character12", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"13", "Character13", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"14", "Character14", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"15", "Character15", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"16", "Character16", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"17", "Character17", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"18", "Character18", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"19", "Character19", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""},
            {"20", "Character20", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""}
          };

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        /*
         * JTable uses this method to determine the default renderer/
         * editor for each cell.  If we didn't implement this method,
         * then the last column would contain text ("true"/"false"),
         * rather than a check box.
         */
        public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
         * editable.
         */
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            //Note that the data/cell address is constant,
            //no matter where the cell appears onscreen.
            if (col < 2) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        /*
         * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
         * data can change.
         */
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            data[row][col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Disable boldface controls.
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE); 

        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("EncounterCalculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        EncounterCalculator newContentPane = new EncounterCalculator();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: oh my god :| please, format your source code so that it's less painful for the eyes. also, try reformatting your question to 2-3 paragraphs. that'll help a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Check your this statement in **actionPerformed** method

`int HP = table.getValueAt(, 3);`

I guess you missed something before "**,**";

And as suggested by **@Hovercraft** in your `getValueAt` method you are returning an `Object` so you need to cast it back to integer.

**EDIT:**

Not related to the error you getting but just a piece of advice (some key points have been told by **@Hovercraft** )

Why are you re-declaring your variable inside `actionPerformed`? Declare them only once.

Answer (score 3):

1+ to sansix for his catch.

Also,

- if the table cell is holding Integer type, then you'll need to cast the Object returned by `getValue(...)` to Integer.
- But your JTable's model **doesn't** hold Integer objects but rather String objects, so your attempt to force it into an int will fail no matter what. You'll want to fix this.
- Never compare Strings with `==`. Use the `equals(...)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method so you can compare Strings for content equality not object equality (same String *object*)
- Your code should adhere to Java naming standards where class names begin with an upper-case letter and the names of variables, methods, and such begin with a lower-case letter. This is mainly important when you want to have others more easily understand your code -- like **us**.

Comment: +1 for looking even deeper with return type of `getValueAt` and nice advice to the OP

Comment: Can you explain why the error I described above doesn't work in greater detail? I cast the return value for the getValueAt as an integer and it still returns the same error. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @user1956201: again, it's *not* an Integer. Look at the type of the data that you're adding to the JTable -- all I can see are Strings, and what will happen if you cast a String to an Integer -- you'll get a cast exception. Consider parsing the String to int via `Integer.parseInt(...)`.